# Setting video tags with a string using Youtube API

Tags: youtube, tags, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

So I have a working uploader using the Youtube api but I have this line:

```
$snippet->setTags(array($tag1, $tag2));
```

currently it sets the tags just fine but i have to have 2 blanks in my form
i want 1 blank where someone can type

```
Youtube,tags,are,cool
```

and each one of those becomes a separate tag! Thanks

Comment: you mean a user from your website to do this. if I am not wrong in understanding your question right

Comment: Yes, I want a user on my site to be able to type Youtube,tags,are,cool into an input field and the youtube api puts each one of those to a seperate tag.

Comment: you need to do with form in which a input text. get value from text and then put it down in your function, which used to upload video to youtube.

Comment: I know. But the $snippet->setTags needs an array. But I only have a string

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an form, with text input, get the value from it then use function which used to upload videos to youtube. You will done with it.

Again, $snippet->setTags need an array. Then use

```
 $value = $_POST['{name of your text field}'];    
 preg_split("/,/", trim($value," "));
```

Use , to make difference in for each tags. 
it gives you an array of tag, even you entered only one value. Hope it helps you.